# tf.dataSync() does not return tensor from BlazeFaceModel in a readable form

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow.js

I am using BlazeFaceModel to detect faces before sending the faces to another model using Tensorflow.js

When I am using a custom model and trying to get the tensor output I used the code below and it worked at returning the tensors.

```
    const returnTensors = true;
    const faces = await blazeModel.estimateFaces(tensor, returnTensors);
    if (faces !== null) {
      // Download the tensors to view the shape
      const face = faces.dataSync();
      face.forEach((pred, i) => {
        console.log(`x: ${i}, pred: ${pred}`);
      });
    }
```

But it throws the following error when applying on the tensor output from BlazeFaceModel:

```
faces.dataSync is not a function. (In 'faces.dataSync()', 'faces.dataSync' is undefined)
```

**Output from console.log(faces)**

```
Array [
  Object {
    "bottomRight": Tensor {
      "dataId": Object {},
      "dtype": "float32",
      "id": 60793,
      "isDisposedInternal": false,
      "kept": false,
      "rankType": "1",
      "scopeId": 116528,
      "shape": Array [
        2,
      ],
      "size": 2,
      "strides": Array [],
    },
    "landmarks": Tensor {
      "dataId": Object {},
      "dtype": "float32",
      "id": 60795,
      "isDisposedInternal": false,
      "kept": false,
      "rankType": "2",
      "scopeId": 116532,
      "shape": Array [
        6,
        2,
      ],
      "size": 12,
      "strides": Array [
        2,
      ],
    },
    "probability": Tensor {
      "dataId": Object {},
      "dtype": "float32",
      "id": 60785,
      "isDisposedInternal": false,
      "kept": false,
      "rankType": "1",
      "scopeId": 116495,
      "shape": Array [
        1,
      ],
      "size": 1,
      "strides": Array [],
    },
    "topLeft": Tensor {
      "dataId": Object {},
      "dtype": "float32",
      "id": 60792,
      "isDisposedInternal": false,
      "kept": false,
      "rankType": "1",
      "scopeId": 116526,
      "shape": Array [
        2,
      ],
      "size": 2,
      "strides": Array [],
    },
  },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

faces is not a tensor. It is an array of json with key values where the values are tensor. If you would like to get all the tensors at once in an array, `Object.values(faces[0])` can be used

```
tensors = Object.values(faces[0]) // array of tensor
tensors.map(t => t.dataSync()) // download the value of the tensor to a js array

// alternatively they can all be converted to a big tensor before using only once dataSync()
```

Comment: Thanks that worked but its returning arrays of different sizes. I am trying to send the tensors of the detected faces to another model to perform a classification task on them. 

So which one would only contain the tensors of the face?

Comment: Would I have to just reshape the tensors here into the shape required by my model then make predictions on them?

Comment: What do your model expect ? Because faces contains several data: the probability, the landmarks, topleft, topLeft, bottomRight.

Comment: Well I just need a cropped image of the faces. Which will be reshaped into a [1,224,224,3] tensor which the other model expects as input.

Comment: I'm thinking with the bounding boxes I could just crop the image based on that and send it for prediction but I'm open to whatever you suggest.

Comment: Hey could you help me out with getting the faces cropped with the bounding boxes?

Comment: Can you please open a related question ?

Comment: If you could go under the latest question on my profile it's there.